# Pedagogical reasons for closed-book exams in graduate-level courses?

Tags: exams, reference-request, teaching

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at the pedagogical benefits of assessing students with closed-book exams for graduate-level courses (vs. open-book exams)?

I'm mostly interested in computer science and math education in the USA, if the answer is field- or country-dependent.

Comment: When I took grad classes in CS, we were given the option of closed book vs open book. Closed book would be "easier" and focus on conceptual core questions, while "open book" would involve writing code rather than core questions. Arguably speaking, mastery comes more out of a closed book test. In fact, lots of places I interviewed for a job had me write code on a white board or a piece of paper with no help after school. That being said, we stopped having exams after the intro and theory courses in favor of software as homework.

Comment: Related: [Are open-book exams generally a superior way to test understanding on practical courses?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/are-open-book-exams-generally-a-superior-way-to-test-understanding-on-practical)

Comment: Related: [Is it good practice to let students consult their text materials during exams?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17763/is-it-good-practice-to-let-students-consult-their-text-materials-during-exams)

Comment: I think it also depends on what you count as a "closed book" exam.  For my Masters, all of my exams were what I would consider "closed book" (i.e. no material whatsoever allowed to be brought in to the exam) but all included a list of common equations as part of the exam packet; some would consider that list of equations to constitute an "open book" exam.

Comment: You need to provide a context or narrow down the scope. In the current form, one can ask the same question for **open-book** exams. Without a context, it seems more like asking for opinions rather than an answer to a query.

Comment: @Parrhesiastes Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question to avoid excessively opinion-biased answers. Please let me know if that's okay now.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you're trying to teach, and what you're trying to assess.

If your goal is to convey concepts, or to teach the things that everyone needs to be able to do without consulting references in order to be productive, closed book may be entirely appropriate.

If your goal is to test their ability to combine and apply the concepts, open book may be more appropriate.

(And yes, I too remember tests with "official" cheat sheets as a balance between these. Then again, I also remember one test whose official cheat sheet was essentially a set of mathematical jokes, because the test itself didn't require any of the rote-memorization material. Then again again, I also remember closed book tests where one of the tools I used was a set of mnemonics that would let me quickly scribble out my own cheat sheet for the formulas/simplifications I most needed -- I can still recite "quasineutrality, uniformity, equilibrium, low-level injection, steady state" but I'd have to hit the books to again remember how those assumptions were used.)

Answer (score 3):

A Google search for "research on open book testing" gives many results.  For example, there is a paper "Examining the testing effect with open- and closed-book tests" by Agarwal, Karpicke, Kang, Roediger and McDermott (http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/acp.1391) with abstract as follows:

> Two experiments examined the testing effect with open-book tests, in
>   which students view notes and textbooks while taking the test, and
>   closed-book tests, in which students take the test without viewing
>   notes or textbooks. Subjects studied prose passages and then restudied
>   or took an open- or closed-book test. Taking either kind of test, with
>   feedback, enhanced long-term retention relative to conditions in which
>   subjects restudied material or took a test without feedback. Open-book
>   testing led to better initial performance than closed-book testing,
>   but this benefit did not persist and both types of testing produced
>   equivalent retention on a delayed test. Subjects predicted they would
>   recall more after repeated studying, even though testing enhanced
>   long-term retention more than restudying. These experiments
>   demonstrate that the testing effect occurs with both open- and
>   closed-book tests, and that subjects fail to predict the effectiveness
>   of testing relative to studying in enhancing later recall.